# Find all integer solutions to this Diophantine equation containing square root

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all integer solutions of the Diophantine equation
> $$b=\sqrt{\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{ac+1}}$$

My work:

Squaring both sides twice $$b^4=c+2\sqrt{c\cdot(ac+1)}+ac+1$$

Since $b$ is an integer, $c$ and $ac+1$ both have to be squares as they have no common factor.

So we can say
$$\begin{align}
c=y^2\\
ac+1=x^2\\
x+y=b^2\\
\end{align}$$
where $x,y$ are some arbitrary integers. Eliminating $c$, we get $$x^2-ay^2=1$$ Thus we came to the Pell's equation. There are infinitely many solutions of this equation but, solutions with $x+y=$ square are rare. By **trial and error** one can find $1$ solution or maybe more. But I'm not able to do it by generalized method.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First passage should have $b^4$ instead of $b$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio thanks..typo corrected

Comment: You can eliminate $y$ as well when you eliminate $c$. Then the question remains: When does $(b^2-x)^2$ divide $x^2-1$ for integers $b$ and $x$.

Comment: @abcdefu  please get in the habit of   giving the **source** of each problem;  that would usually be a link.

Comment: could the difficulty come from assuming that both $c$ and $ac+1$ are square integers. If you relax that condition, then maybe you can find more solutions. This is just a guess. Say $c=9$ and $a=136$ so that $c(ac+1)=9(9*136+1)=9*1225=3^2*35^2=105^2$. I didn't check if it leads to $b^4=integer$.